# Return vector elements as a single integer

Tags: arrays, matlab

In MATLAB, how can I return the contents of a vector as a single integer. For example, if `a = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]`, then I want a function that returns the number `123456789`.

It's almost squeeze but removing all dimensions!!

My current solution is to read the vector as a string using `sprintf` with a format of `'%i'`, then convert it to a number using `str2double`. That's ok if you only need to use it a few times, but fairly inefficient if it's being used 100000 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
result = a*10.^(numel(a)-1:-1:0).';
```

or equivalently

```
result = sum(a.*10.^(numel(a)-1:-1:0));
```

They seem to be about equally fast.

Answer (score 1):

One approach assuming the input as a vector of one-digit numbers with `str2num` and `num2str` -

```
str2num(num2str(a,'%1d'))
```

Or

```
str2num(char(a+48)) %// Thanks to Luis!
```

Or

```
str2double(char(a+48))
```