# Concatenate three numbers together in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation

Suppose that we have these three numbers:

```
a=2;
b=3;
c=5;
```

I want concatenate these three numbers to have:

```
out = 235; %// (double variable not string)
```

How can i do this with and without (prefer this) converting it to string?

Comment: You want the number `235` or the vector `[2,3,5]`? Either do `100*a + 10*b + c` or `[a,b,c]`

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874293/return-vector-elements-as-a-single-integer) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083808/matlab-convert-array-to-number/26084023#26084023).

Answer (score 4):

A more general approach that [Dan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332094/concatenate-three-numbers-together-in-matlab#comment56405955_34332094): If you have a vector `v` of digits, you can convert it into a single number by

```
v = [a,b,c]; %// [2,3,5]
out = v * (10.^( (numel(v)-1):-1:0 ) )'
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Shai's solution, you can use a combination of [`num2str`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) and [`str2num`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html).

```
v = [a; b; c]; %// [2;3;5]
out = str2num(num2str(v)')
out =    
   235
```

Or the faster, but maybe harder to read alternative:

```
out = str2num(char('0'+v))
```

Now, if you have to do this many times, you can assign this to an [anonymous function handle](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
f = @(v) str2num(num2str(v(:))')
```

Now you can simply do `f(v)`. This will work with both horizontal and vertical arrays, due to the use of `(:)`.

Note that you can turn Shai's approach into a function handle too:

```
f = @(v) v*(10.^((numel(v)-1):-1:0))';
```